# how to make site-packages lower in priority for package search

Tags: python

I have set the sys.path to `[]` in a python script and it is still able to load a package from site-packages. How is that possible? How do i get site-packages to be lower in priority from a directory i want it to load a package from?

Comment: What's your `PYTHONPATH` look like? Per https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html: "sys.path is initialized from these locations: (1) The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified), (2) PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH), and (3) the installation-dependent default."  Also see https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` hasn't been set in the environment. When i check `os.environ` there is no key called `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: You may need to set one in this environment.